# dependency loop : to deploy gitlab using awx ansible i need a repository

Tags: puppet, ansible, gitlab, ansible-tower, rundeck

I want to deploy gitlab using awx and ansible ( or with puppet and rundeck ) and to do it i need a repository ( SCM : gitlab ) , the thing is i want to deploy gitlab but i need a gitlab , i can't find a documentation that give a soluyion , is there any solution for this problem ?
i found that i can put the roles on the filesystem where AWX is installed instead of using SCM , is it the only solution for this problem ?

Comment: Why do you believe you need a repository to deploy gitlab using ansible?

Comment: not in ansible , but in awx

Answer (score 0):

Thats correct - it is similar to the problem of chickens and eggs or when to stop Paranoia or how to install Ansible with Ansible itself. There is no way out. If you want to bootstrap an AWX environment you need some sources. Your AWX needs the "input" where playbooks, roles, etc. are stored. If it is inside your Gitlab (which isn't existing), where is the playbook before installing Gitlab?

So - you have a running AWX (maybe based on the Github role from the AWX team).

If you have a ZIP file (with your playbooks like the one to install Gitlab). Then you can copy that zip file to the AWX host and configure a new Project within AWX. So - it could be a "manual" project and enter the path, where you unpacked the ZIP file. With that project you could rollout your Gitlab and - if it is good enough - create there a project with the content from the ZIP file. After that you can switch to that Git-Repository.

To create a "none-Git-project" go to AWX>Project and press the + button. Then under SCM type choose "manual" and enter the path on the AWX host.